# How can I merge the file by ID?

Tags: python, shutil

I've got a problem to merge 2 .txt files into 1 txt file. I could merge them, however I need to merge them in the same line by ID. Then, I have to write the data in the same line ID.

This code merge, but below the txt

```
import shutil;
print("Enter 'x' for exit.");
filename1 = input("Enter first file name to merge: ");
if filename1 == 'x':
    exit();
else:
    filename2 = input("Enter second file name to merge: ");
    filename3 = input("Create a new file to merge content of two file inside this file: ");
    print();
    print("Merging the content of two file in",filename3);
    with open(filename3, "wb") as wfd:
        for f in [filename1, filename2]:
            with open(f, "rb") as fd:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd, 1024*1024*10);
    print("\nContent merged successfully.!");
    print("Want to see ? (y/n): ");
    check = input();
    if check == 'n':
        exit();
    else:
        print();
        c = open(filename3, "r");
        print(c.read());
        c.close();
```

What I have: *(input files)*

text1.txt:

> Id    x   y
>   1 6655.5 -3132.0

text2.txt:

> Id  e n z
>   1 111 222 333

I wanna get for example: *(expected output)*

> Id    x   y   e   n   z
>   1 6655.5 -3132.0 111 222 333

Comment: Can you provide sample input & output (expected & actual)?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your `.txt` files? Just samples would be fine.

Comment: Hey guys, can you understand now?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming identical number and order of IDs in both text files, you could do this:

```
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('text2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    f1_text = f1.read().splitlines()
    f2_text = f2.read().splitlines()
with open('text3.txt', 'w+') as f3:
    for i, item in enumerate(f1_text):
        value1 = f1_text[i].split(None, 1)[1].rstrip('\n')
        value2 = f2_text[i].split(None, 1)[1].rstrip('\n')
        if i == 0:
            i = 'Id'
        f3.write(str(i) + ' ' + value1 + ' ' + value2 + '\n')

with open('text3.txt', 'r') as f3:
    print(f3.read())

Input:
-----
"TEXT1.txt"
Id x y
1 6655.5 -3132.0
2 1122.3 -1234.0
3 4455.6 -5678.9
-----
"TEXT2.txt"
Id e n z 
1 111 222 333
2 444 555 666
3 777 888 999  
=====
Output:
"TEXT3.txt"
## Id x y e n z 
## 1 6655.5 -3132.0 111 222 333
## 2 1122.3 -1234.0 444 555 666
## 3 4455.6 -5678.9 777 888 999
```

(Caveat: this will work on smaller files because the code below reads the entire text files into memory.  If your files are very large, then you will need to adjust this using some *generator*)